# How do i get data from a json object from api and populate a spinner in kotlin using retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm making an app that can read from Api and populate a kotlin spinner. isSuccesful and all response. extensions are not found, how do i fix it?

This is the url i'm getting the json objects from:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos
open it, it's public.

I set up the dependencies for retrofita dn gson, as well as enabling view binding and user permission for internet.

I have these files:

1. MainActivity.kl with this code:

```
package com.example.merchandizecodedesk

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.merchandizecodedesk.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.IOException
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.HttpException


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var apiService: RetrofitInterface

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        apiService = ApiClient.retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface::class.java)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try{
                val response = apiService.get()

                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    val items = response.body()?.map {it.title}
                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items)
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                    binding.spinner.adapter = adapter
                }else {
                    Log.e("MainActivity","yo")
                }
                /*val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items)
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                binding.spinner.adapter = adapter*/
            }catch (e: IOException){
                Log.e("MainActivity","IOException")
            }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.message.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. RetrofitInterface.kt:

```
package com.example.merchandizecodedesk

import retrofit2.http.GET

interface RetrofitInterface {
    @GET("/todos/")
    fun get(): List<ToDoItem>
}
```

3. ApiClient.kt:

```
package com.example.merchandizecodedesk

import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object ApiClient {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

    val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

4. ToDoItem.kt:

```
package com.example.merchandizecodedesk

data class ToDoItem(
    val completed: Boolean,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val userId: Int
)
```

5. ativity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm getting the error: Unresolved reference: isSuccessful, but response.body also isnt working, just the compiler hasn't gotten to it. What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

To get the isSuccessfull and body() methods to your retrofit response you need to wrap the return type of your get method around the Response class of the retrofit2 package.

```
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface RetrofitInterface {
    @GET("/todos/")
    fun get(): Response<List<ToDoItem>>
}
```